# AndroidStudio fragment code stop working after cycling through other fragments

Tags: java, android-fragments

In AndroidStudio I am creating a project that is for stocks/finance, and I realized halfway through making it that when I ran the Android Emulator (Pixel 5 - API 33) and after cycling through my home, dashboard, and notifications fragments that when I return to the home fragment the switches (Stock News Filter, and Earnings Beat Filter) no longer work when I click them? They only work when I stay in the tab and don't switch fragments. I have posted my MainActivity.java and a new file I had created called StockiestService.java in this [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/gfXTcbxs): https://pastebin.com/gfXTcbxs

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 
        com.example.stockiest.databinding.ActivityMainBinding binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
```

I had attempted to edit the onDestroy code a little because I had assumed somehow my first fragment would destroy after switching to different tabs but this didn't work.

I also attempted to re-write my onCreate function in my MainActivity.java because I assumed somehow it was only onCreating certain portions of the code one time.

I'd really appreciate some help because I am quite lost on where I went wrong,
Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: @JonR85 do you see what might be wrong with my Android Studio fragments seemingly creating a new unusable thread when continuing to the home fragment after switching through the dashboard and notifications fragments?